# what is the difference of having ['$scope' next to function($scope) to doesn't have ['$scope'

Tags: angularjs, scope, angularjs-scope

what's the difference of this two code?

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
  myApp.controller('GreetingCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.greeting = {
    message: 'Hola!'
    };
 });

myApp.controller('HiCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.double = {
    text: 'Hello'
    };
});
```

TO

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
  myApp.controller('GreetingCtrl',['$scope', function($scope) {
     $scope.greeting = {
       message: 'Hola!'
       };
  }]);

  myApp.controller('HiCtrl',['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.double = {
      text: 'Hello'
      };
  }]);`
```

THAT having a ['$scope', next to function($scope) is not working if i have 2 controllers in 1 module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the AngularJS doc [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di). Basically, adding the `['$scope',` allows you to use the Dependency Injection and still make it work with the JS minification process.

The minifier will change `function($scope)` in `function(a)` and you will lose the `$scope` dependency. Since minifiers don't compress Strings, `['$scope',` will remain the same and AngularJS will be able to parse it.

FYI: if you are using Grunt and you don't want to use this `['$scope',` notation, this [module](https://github.com/btford/grunt-ngmin) can be helpful.

> `angular.module('myApp', [])
>   .controller('GreetingCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
>      $scope.greeting = {
>        message: 'Hola!'
>      };
>      $http.get('http://www.google.com');
>   }]);`

Comment: Thanks, can you show me? how it works using ['$scope' i'm just new in programming especially angularjs